# Uppercase random characters in a NSString

Tags: objective-c, string, random

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to a problem. I have an essentially random alphanumeric string that I'm generating on the fly:

```
NSString *string = @"e04325ca24cf20ac6bd6ebf73c376b20ac57192dad83b22602264e92dac076611b51142ae12d2d92022eb2c77f";
```

You can see that there are no special characters, just numbers and letters, and all the letters are lowercase. Changing all the letters in this string to uppercase is easy:

```
[string capitalizedString];
```

The hard part is that I want to capitalize random characters in this string, not all of them. For example, this could be the output on one execution:

```
E04325cA24CF20ac6bD6eBF73C376b20Ac57192DAD83b22602264e92daC076611b51142AE12D2D92022Eb2C77F
```

This could be the output on another, since it's random:

```
e04325ca24cf20aC6bd6eBF73C376B20Ac57192DAd83b22602264E92dAC076611B51142AE12D2d92022EB2c77f
```

In case it makes this easier, let's say I have two variables as well:

```
int charsToUppercase = 12;//hardcoded value for how many characters to uppercase here
int totalChars = 90;//total string length
```

In this instance it would mean that 12 random characters out of the 90 in this string would be uppercased. What I've figured out so far is that I can loop through each char in the string relatively easily:

```
NSUInteger len = [string length];
unichar buffer[len+1];

[string getCharacters:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0, len)];

NSLog(@"loop through each char");
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%C", buffer[i]);
}
```

Still stuck with selecting random chars in this loop to uppercase, so not all are uppercased. I'm guessing a condition in the for loop could do the trick well, given that it's random enough.

Comment: First: get random index of question about random, without repeat, etc.) (there are plenty, then replace that character (`NSRange range = NSMakeRange(randomIndex,1); [mutableString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:[[mutableString substringFromRange:range] uppercase]];`), but another question is if the character to uppercase is a number, does it count as a modification?

Comment: Thanks @Larme, interesting idea. In the context of this puzzle, let's say it doesn't count if it's a number.

Comment: What do you want to do if there are only 12 letters in the string?

Comment: @JoshCaswell good question - the charsToUppercase int is calculated on-the-fly, as a random number less than the number of letters in the string. So the weirdest that could happen is that 100% of the letters in the string are uppercased.

Comment: Oh, so the question is just what the probability is for each letter, then.

Comment: Ah, probability is a great idea here. I'm already going through each character in the string during the loop. A probability could decide whether or not to uppercase the character, regardless of whether it's a letter or number. Don't even need to pre-calculate how many chars to uppercase, since a probably condition could do that anyway. I'll play with that idea - thanks @JoshCaswell

Comment: I've edited to suggest a tighter loop if given an uppercase probability for any character encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, not particularly concerned with efficiency, but not silly efficiency-wise either: create an array characters in the original string, building an index of which ones are letters along the way...

```
NSString *string = @"e04325ca24cf20ac6bd6ebf73c376b20ac57192dad83b22602264e92dac076611b51142ae12d2d92022eb2c77f";
NSMutableArray *chars = [@[] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *letterIndexes = [@[] mutableCopy];

for (int i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
    unichar ch = [string characterAtIndex:i];
    // add each char as a string to a chars collection
    [chars addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", ch]];
    // record the index of letters
    if ([[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:ch]) {
        [letterIndexes addObject:@(i)];
    }
}
```

Now, select randomly from the `letterIndexes` (removing them as we go) to determine which letters shall be upper case.  Convert the member of the `chars` array at that index to uppercase...

```
int charsToUppercase = 12;

for (int i=0; i<charsToUppercase && letterIndexes.count; i++) {
    NSInteger randomLetterIndex = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)(letterIndexes.count));
    NSInteger indexToUpdate = [letterIndexes[randomLetterIndex] intValue];
    [letterIndexes removeObjectAtIndex:randomLetterIndex];

    [chars replaceObjectAtIndex:indexToUpdate withObject:[chars[indexToUpdate] uppercaseString]];
}
```

Notice the `&&` check on `letterIndexes.count`.  This guards against the condition where `charsToUppercase` exceeds the number of `chars`.  The upper bound of conversions to uppercase is all of the letters in the original string.

Now all that's left is to join the `chars` array into a string...

```
NSString *result = [chars componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

**EDIT** Looking discussion in OP comments, you could, instead of a`charsToUppercase` input parameter, be given a probability of uppercase change as an input.  That would compress this idea into a single loop with a little less data transformation...

```
NSString *string = @"e04325ca24cf20ac6bd6ebf73c376b20ac57192dad83b22602264e92dac076611b51142ae12d2d92022eb2c77f";

float upperCaseProbability = 0.5;
NSMutableString *result = [@"" mutableCopy];

for (int i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
    NSString *chString = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    BOOL toUppercase = arc4random_uniform(1000) / 1000.0 < upperCaseProbability;

    if (toUppercase) {
        chString = [chString uppercaseString];
    }
    [result appendString:chString];
}
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

However this assumes a given uppercase probability for any character, not any letter, so it won't result in a predetermined number of letters changing case.

Comment: Thanks @danh, both your answers are interesting approaches that should do the trick.