# Is there a way to capitalize letters randomly in a sentence in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, string

Just want a way to capitalize letters in a sentence randomly. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you referred this SO link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380116/uppercase-random-characters-in-a-nsstring?

Comment: Thank you very much but i can not read objective-c code (I am beginner)

Comment: Ok so I am adding the code for swift.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var string: String = "your string"
var chars: [Any] = []
var letterIndexes: [Any] = []
for i in 0..<string.characters.count {
    var ch: unichar = string[i]
    // add each char as a string to a chars collection
    chars.append("\(ch)")
    // record the index of letters
    if CharacterSet.letters.characterIsMember(ch) {
        letterIndexes.append((i))
    }
}
```

select randomly from the letterIndexes to determine which letters will be upper case. Convert the member of the chars array at that index to uppercase.

```
var charsToUppercase: Int = 12
var i = 0
while i < charsToUppercase && letterIndexes.count {
    var randomLetterIndex: Int? = arc4random_uniform(((letterIndexes.count) as? u_int32_t))
    var indexToUpdate = CInt(letterIndexes[randomLetterIndex])
    letterIndexes.remove(at: randomLetterIndex)
    chars[indexToUpdate] = chars[indexToUpdate].uppercased()
    i += 1
}
```

ow all that's left is to join the chars array into a string.

```
var result: String = (chars as NSArray).componentsJoined(byString: "")
print("\(result)")
```

Refer [this link for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380116/uppercase-random-characters-in-a-nsstring).